# Problems mounting a ubi image using QEMU

Tags: arm, qemu, ubifs

I'm trying to emulate a *nand* flash with *qemu* and use that to mount an existent *ubifs* image on the virtual machine.

I added a *nand* device and a drive of the type *mtd*, resulting on the following command:

```
$ qemu-system-arm -nographic -M virt -m 64 -device nand,chip_id=0x59  -drive if=mtd,format=raw,file=data.ubi -kernel openwrt-armvirt-32-zImage-initramfs 
Warning: Orphaned drive without device: id=mtd0,file=data.ubi,if=mtd,bus=0,unit=0
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.19.56 (buildbot@builds) (gcc version 7.4.0 (OpenWrt GCC 7.4.0 r10348-577174cf60)) #0 SMP Tue Jun 25 14:46:01 2019
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [412fc0f1] revision 1 (ARMv7), cr=30c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, PIPT instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: linux,dummy-virt
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] psci: probing for conduit method from DT.
[    0.000000] psci: PSCIv0.2 detected in firmware.
...
```

I can't access to the *data.ubi* probably because of the following warning:

> "Warning: Orphaned drive without device"

How can I add the *ubi* image to the *nand* device correctly?

Comment: What are you trying to do/debug?  You can loop back mount ubi on an x86 host and share with the qemu system if you just need the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to link the `-drive` and `-device` via an `id` parameter:

```
qemu-system-arm \
  `: [...]` \
  -device nand,chip_id=0x59,id=myubiflash \
  -drive if=mtd,format=raw,file=data.ubi,id=myubiflash \
  `: [...]`
```

If you *really* read the message carefully, you'll notice that the drive id defaults to `mtd0`:

> Warning: Orphaned drive without device: **id=mtd0**,file=data.ubi,if=mtd,bus=0,unit=0

And of course qemu can't magically guess that you meant to define the `-device nand` for the drive.

The error message is exactly on the spot here.

---

#### *Edit*

I'll admit, no perfect understanding of the layers of syntax in QEMU commandline on my side either.
Also, the [QEMU doc](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#Block-device-options) isn't the easiest to read; however it has this passage:

> A block driver node created with -blockdev can be used for a guest device by specifying its node name for the drive property in a -device argument that defines a block device.

`-blockdev` is synonym to `-drive` in this context.

If I can interpret it right, the meaning of this is that instead of

- `-device […],id=foo`, `-drive […],id=foo`

you're supposed to use

- `-device […],drive=foo`, `-drive […],id=foo`

Can't test this ATM, but either of those should make it work for you.

Comment: Nice! It solves the problem. However, now it gives me another error regarding the machine type support `qemu-system-arm: -drive if=mtd,format=raw,file=100000.uubi,id=myubiflash: machine type does not support if=mtd,bus=0,unit=0` any idea about this?

Comment: @PRVS try running `qemu-system-arm -machine help` and selecting which Arm board you emulate. `-machine virt` might be a good choice here

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that the arm's that are possible to emulate does not have support to NAND, so, it has been dificulty for me to find a solution.